# Audio and video mixing with php or .net

Tags: php, .net, asp.net, video-streaming, audio-recording

Here are my queries :

**[1] Audio File Mixing**

Need to mix (not merge) 2 audio files (.mp3) to create one single file (.mp3). The bit rates of the audio files to be mixed will be same and the bit rate of the final mixed file should also remain the same.

**[2] Create Custom Video**

Also need to create video (.mp4 or .mpg) with few different transitions (atleast 5-6) by using some available images to show as a slide show and an audio file to be played in the background.

All this is required to be achieved using .NET and PHP both. So need suggestions related to 3rd party tools/libraries (**free or paid**) that can be used.

Let me know if any more details are required.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to investigate http://sox.sourceforge.net/, which is a command line audio processing utility. You can invoke it from either PHP or .NET (a win binary is available) by executing it via the shell.

Never used it, and it's not clear how and what exactly you want to mix. You have to consult the manpage http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html but unless you need effects it's probably just:

```
system("sox input1.mp3 input2.mp3 mix output.mp3");
```

Merging audio and images into a video file is quite simple with [`ffmpeg`](http://www.google.com/search?q=ffmpeg), where it's again simple to invoke it via the commandline. [`mencoder`](http://www.google.com/search?q=mencoder) allows for more transitions.